# Python POO y diccionarios - Acumular datos dentro de una clase

Tags: python, poo, bucle-for, herencia

No se si alguien más ya preguntó esto, busqué pero no encontré algo relacionado. Una disculpa si se repite la pregunta.
Estoy empezando con programación orientada a objetos en Python, estoy aprendiendo Herencia y Composición.
En el script que estoy haciendo, primero hago una Clase llamada Animal que tiene dos parámetros: name y category (en el cual va la categoria del animal (Canido, Reptil, Felino, etc).
Despues agrego dos subclases heredadas de Animal (Turtle y Snake).
Por ultimo una clase Zoo, en la cual agrego entradas a un diccionario y en el cual se debe sumar 1 cada que aparezca un animal con la misma categoría.

```
class Animal:
    # Define the class parameters #
    name = ""
    category = ""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_category(self, category):
        self.category = category


##################
# Turtle category #
class Turtle(Animal):
    pass
##################
# Snake category #
class Snake(Animal):
    pass
##################  

# New class Zoo
class Zoo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_animals = {}
        # create a new dict 

    def add_animal(self, animal):
        self.current_animals[animal.name] = animal.category
        # add entries to the current_animals dict
    def total_of_category(self, category):
        result = 0 # initialize variable
        for animal in self.current_animals.values(): 
            # start counting how many
            # of every animal category 
            # is in the dict
            if animal == category:
                result += 1
        return result
# inherit variable

zoo = Zoo()
```

hasta ahora he podido agregar entradas al diccionario, sin embargo no se está realizando la adición a la variable result dentro de la función total_of_category.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, ya no se me ocurre otra solución.
Muchisimas gracias, y de nuevo una disculpa si la pregunta está repetida.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la relación que tiene las clases `Turtle` y `Snake` con la clase `Zoo`?

Comment: Agregando una entrada tipo: `zoo.add_animal(turtle)`

Comment: A ver si entendí que necesitas para ayudarte: Necesitas que, cada vez que se añada un animal, se sume uno a la lista de animales **por categoría** que tienes almacenado en un diccionario. Luego, con  `total_of_category()`, mostrar cuentos animales hay de la categoría especificada.
¿Es así?

Comment: si, asi es, cuando imprimo el `total_of_category("Reptil")` por ejemplo, me da 0, cuando añado dos entradas por ejemplo `turtle = Turtle("Turtle")` y `snake = Snake("Snake")` y `snake.set_category("Reptile")` `turtle.set_category("Reptile")`. Al momento de agregarlo a zoo `zoo.add_animal(turtle)
zoo.add_animal(snake)` y correr el total_of_category, me da 0

Comment: Hola Samuel, con el código que muestras en el comentario, es imposible que `print(zoo.total_of_category("Reptile"))` te de 0....

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado la lógica de algunas de tus funciones para que se haga más fácil e intuitivo saber que está Pasando.

En este caso, lo que he hecho es que tu diccionario `current_animals` de la clase `Zoo` se clasifique por categorías y que cada categoría, almacene los animales son de dicha categoría en una lista. También he de decir que la función valida si el animal que está recibiendo tiene una categoría asignada (lanza un error en caso de que no). La función `add_animal()` quedaría así:

```
def add_animal(self, animal):
    if (animal.category):
      try:
          self.current_animals[animal.category.lower()] += [animal.name]
      except KeyError:
          self.current_animals[animal.category.lower()] = [animal.name]
    else:
         raise Exception("The animal cannot be added. It does not have category")
```

La función `total_of_category()` busca, en el diccionario, la categoría que se le ha pedido. En caso de no encontrarla, devuelve `0`, en caso de que la categoría sí exista, devuelve la longitud de la lista asignada a la categoría encontrada. En código se vería algo así:

```
def total_of_category(self, category):
    category_searched = self.current_animals[category.lower()]
    if (category_searched):
        return len(category_searched)
    else: return 0
```

Ahora puedes añadir los animales que desees y tu clase `Zoo` te devolverá la cantidad de animales registrados sin ningún problema.